Proving a sequence of functions is Cauchy, but not convergent in a normed space.

$$f_n : [0,2] \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto f_n(x)= \begin{cases} x^n & \text{if } x \in[0,1] \\ 1 & \text{if } x \in (1,2] \end{cases}$$ for $$n \in \Bbb N$$. Show that the sequence $$f_n$$ is a Cauchy sequence in $$(C^0 ([0,2], L1=|f||_1 )$$, but not convergent. ($$||f||_1$$ which is $$\int \limits _a^b |f(x)| dx)$$

I think I got the Cauchy charateristic (after doing the integral and etc. I got $$\frac {1}{2n+3+\frac {1}{n}} \lt \epsilon $$ ) - which hopefully is correct.
(Inserted calculations: $$\int \limits _0^2 |f(x)| dx)$$ and supposing $$m=2n$$ is follows $$\int \limits _0^2 |x^n-x^m| dx) = |\frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac {x^{m+1}}{m+1}| = |\frac {2^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac {2^{m+1}}{m+1}|$$ and as for $$f(x)=1$$ for $$x=2$$ (see cases) we get $$|\frac {1}{n+1}-\frac {1}{m+1}|$$ = $$ \frac {(m+1)-(n+1)}{(m+1)(n+1)}$$ and expanding (as $$m=2n$$) we get $$\frac {n}{2n^2+3n+1}$$ which, as n approaches infinity, goes towards zero.
But now I've got the problem with showing that it's not convergent.
I tried applying the norm for functions with the integral and defining two limit functions and got $$\frac {1}{n+1} \lt \epsilon$$ concluding that $$f_n \to 0$$ for all $$x \in [0,2]$$, which is incorrect - thus convergence is disproved.
However, I fear there is some fault to my logic.
If someone could help a little, point out a mistake perhaps. Thank you very much.
(Real Analysis is a weak spot of mine and I have some problems with proving such characteristics in general)

What do you mean by "in $(C^0 ([0,2], L1)$"?

Being Cauchy is about the individual terms getting closer together. Can you show that if $m.n>N$, then $|f_n-f_m|<1/N$? To argue the limit doesn’t exist, argue the limit must be the point wise limit almost everywhere. Why isn’t anything like this in the space?

Your post really needs clarifications. Again (please edit your post to answer): what do you mean by "in $(C^0 ([0,2], L1)$"?  It would also be useful for us to help you if you insert the whole computations which led you to $\frac {1}{2n+3+\frac {1}{n}} \lt \epsilon$ and to $\frac {1}{n+1} \lt \epsilon$.

Thank you, much clearer now for what you mean by $(C^0 ([0,2], L1=|f||_1 )$ (you'd better write $(C^0 ([0,2]),|~|_1)$), and for where your $\frac {1}{2n+3+\frac {1}{n}} \lt \epsilon$ comes from. What about your $\frac {1}{n+1} \lt \epsilon$?

Your proof that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy for $\|~\|_1$ is not correct. You checked (with sometimes slightly clumsy formulations) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_{2n}-f_n\|_1=0,$$
but this is not sufficient. What you must prove instead is that
$\|f_m-f_n\|_1\to0$ for $m,n\to0$ independently, i.e. formally:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\quad\forall m,n\ge N\quad\|f_m-f_n\|_1\le\epsilon.$$
Since
$$\|f_m-f_n\|_1=\left|\frac1{m+1}-\frac1{n+1}\right|\le\max\left(\frac1{m+1},\frac1{n+1}\right),$$
you just have to choose $N\ge\frac1\epsilon-1$.
As for the non-convergence of $(f_n)$ in $(C^0([0,2]),\|~\|_1)$, just invoke the uniqueness of limits, noticing that it converges in $(L^1([0,2]),\|~\|_1)$ to the function
$$f: [0,2] \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto \begin{cases}0& \text{if } x \in[0,1)\\ 1 & \text{if } x \in [1,2],\end{cases}$$
which, as an element of $L^1([0,2])$, does not belong to the subspace $C^0([0,2])$, or, phrased more formally: which is not almost everywhere equal to any continuous function. (To prove this last claim, argue like here.)

Thank you very much - that's all very clear.
Just to make sure I haven't misunderstood anything.
"as an element of 1([0,2]), does not belong to the subspace 0([0,2])" - the limit function, right? It's not continuous, that's the whole point, correct?
I wasn't so sure about setting m as 2n, because obviously it's not general, but sometimes you can do it without problems.
Again, thank you very much.

"The limit function $f$, right". But the argument that it is not continuous is not sufficient, because it sometimes happens that a discontinuous function is equal a.e. to a continuous one. You must do some reasoning like in the link at the end of my answer.
